# File exist check dont work

Tags: c

In my code the following function checks libs but it does not work.

```
system("cd /usr/libt");
for(value = 0; value < 19; value++)
{
    if( access( LIB_ARRAY[value], F_OK ) != -1 )
    {
       if (iLang_config == 1)
            printf("%s Existiert bereits.\n", LIB_ARRAY[value]);
        if (iLang_config == 2)
             printf("%s already exists.\n", LIB_ARRAY[value]);
    }
    else
    {
        //snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "fetch http://koridev.eu/download/libs/%s", \
                   LIB_ARRAY[value]);
        //system(buf) ;
        printf("lol ich fehle %s\n",  LIB_ARRAY[value]);
    }
}
```

You can find the full implementation [here](http://pastebin.com/4CT58AAs).

Edit: The `Test.txt` file is existed in `/usr/libt`

Comment: Try this: Remove the line `system("cd /usr/libt");` and call the `access` function with the full path as first argument.

Comment: Thanks. I have solved The Proplem with a buffer http://pastebin.com/cst1D3NW